# How to get Source Maps with "stylify" and "insert-css"

Tags: css, transform, gulp, browserify, stylus

How to get Source Maps with "stylify" and "insert-css" using Browserify / Gulp?

My gulp javascript task is like this:

```
gulp.task('js_watch', ['environmentCheck'], function()
{
  var bundle = function()
  {
    return bundler.bundle()
      .on('start', bundleLogger.start)
      .on('error', handleErrors)
      .pipe(source('bundle.js'))
      // remove console.logs and such
      .pipe(gulpif( global.ENV === 'production', streamify( strip() )))
      // uglify JS and obfuscate in produciton mode only
      .pipe(gulpif( global.ENV === 'production', streamify(uglify({ mangle: global.ENV === 'production' }))))
      .pipe(print())
      .pipe(gulp.dest(global.outputDir + datapaths.dataPath + '/js'))
      .on('end', bundleLogger.end);
  }

  var browserify_instance = browserify({
    // Required watchify args
    cache: {}, packageCache: {}, fullPaths: true,
    // Browserify Options
    entries:    ['./core/js/core.js'],
    extensions: ['.jade', '.styl'],
    debug:      global.ENV === 'development'
  });

  browserify_instance.transform('stylify', {
    use :[ 
      jeet(),
      rupture(), 
      typographic(), 
      axis(), 
      autoprefixer({ browsers: ['ie 7', 'ie 8'] })
    ],
    sourcemap: { inline: global.ENV === 'development' },
    compress: global.ENV === 'production',
  });

  var bundler = watchify(browserify_instance);
  bundler.on('update', bundle); // on any dep update, runs the bundler

  bundle();
});
```

Then in the JS code:

```
var insertCss           = require('insert-css');
insertCss(require('../../stylus/pages/dashboard.styl'));
```

Every option in the Transform options works, except I get no Sourcemaps in the resulting CSS (in the browser).

Answer (score 0):

It appears Stylify only accepts settings passed in with the `set` object.

```
browserify_instance.transform('stylify', {
  use: [...] 
  set: {
    sourcemap: { inline: global.ENV === 'development' },
    compress: global.ENV === 'production'
  }
});
```

Comment: Did didn't have any effect here, I keep getting "<style>…</style>" instead of the file names / line numbers.... :(

Comment: Did you get this to work? What versions of Browserify / Stylify / Insert-css are you using ? I have Browserify@~8.1.3, Stylify@^1.2.0, and insert-css@^0.2.0. Also Node is v0.10.33 and NPM is v2.4.1

Comment: If you did get it to work, perhaps you could make a jsfiddle/codepen or Github repo with some code demonstrating? :) it would be awesome

Comment: Hey sorry for the delayed response. I was able to get sourcemaps to work,  as they're appearing in the `<style>` tag in the `<head>`. However when inspecting any elements in Chrome it points to the `<style>` tag instead of the file that generated the styles. Here is the gulp bundle code I used: https://gist.github.com/TylerK/da699f73b47eaf337465

Comment: Dug a little deeper in to this: If you decode the inline sourcemap, the originating file is correct, though it is attempting to map it to `filename.css`, which doesn't exist. I assume this is why it's not correctly displaying the sourced file in the browsers dev tools.

Comment: I see. Is there a way to make the sourcemaps show in the dev tools?

Comment: Using the code on the gist, the sourcemap itself was being inlined into the `<style>` tag in the head. I used an online base64 decoder to see what it was doing.